# Llenado de memoria por mensajes de entrada/salida webservices

Tags: java, webservice, servidor

Tengo una aplicación web java (versión 1.6) que hace numerosas llamadas a servicios externos para obtener/intercambiar información. Las llamadas se hacen a través de librerías generadas a partir de un wsdl (con wsimport).

El problema que presenta la aplicación es que, se observa un aumento progresivo del uso de la memoria (OldGen) durante toda la jornada, lo que hace que en un determinado momento se produzcan FULL GC y se ralentice mucho.

Examinando un volcado de memoria, he visto que el mayor objeto en memoria es un elemento de tipo byte[] que contiene principalmente, las llamadas (entradas/respuestas) que se intercambian con los sistemas externos que comentaba. Incluso también se ven en ese objeto, String con nombres de clases, o URLs que se usan en la aplicación,....

El nivel de log de la aplicación está puesto en modo ERROR por lo que no correspondería que se grabasen esos logs. Además, por el formato de esos logs de entrada/salida, no son establecidos por el propio código sino que es algo que, supongo, se establece en la propia máquina virtual (sunone7).

¿Alquien tiene alguna pista sobre esto?¿Como saber quien crea ese objeto de trazas y como se puede deshabilitar esa opción o limpiarlo?¿Hay alguna opción en el server.xml o en algun otro sitio que pueda estar haciendo esto?

Un saludo y gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia tal y como está: no sabemos ni los frameworks que usas, ni el contenedor, ni cómo se manejan las instancias de los clientes que consumen esos servicios. Las razones para fugas de memoria podrían ser variadas